# Parsing text file in perl

Tags: perl

I have a text file as below. 
I need to find keywords as "(number) tests from (number) test cases ran" and store the number.
In the below case the number is 67.
Secondly, I need to find "PASSED" keyword and then followed by "(number) tests".
In the below case it is 67 tests. How can i do it.

Tanks,
Sharath

```
< 0x00000: 5b 2d 2d 2d  2d 2d 2d 2d  2d 2d 2d 5d  20 31 34 20  [----------] 14 
< 0x00010: 74 65 73 74  73 20 66 72  6f 6d 20 44  49 53 41 42  tests from DISAB
< 0x00020: 4c 45 44 5f  47 65 6e 65  72 69 63 44  52 4d 54 65  LED_GenericDRMTe
< 0x00030: 73 74 20 28  31 32 38 34  39 20 6d 73  20 74 6f 74  st (12849 ms tot
< 0x00040: 61 6c 29 0d  0a 0d 0a 5b  2d 2d 2d 2d  2d 2d 2d 2d  al)....[--------
< 0x00050: 2d 2d 5d 20  47 6c 6f 62  61 6c 20 74  65 73 74 20  --] Global test 
< 0x00060: 65 6e 76 69  72 6f 6e 6d  65 6e 74 20  74 65 61 72  environment tear
< 0x00070: 2d 64 6f 77  6e 0d 0a 5b  3d 3d 3d 3d  3d 3d 3d 3d  -down..[========
< 0x00080: 3d 3d 5d 20  36 37 20 74  65 73 74 73  20 66 72 6f  ==] 67 tests fro
< 0x00090: 6d 20 34 20  74 65 73 74  20 63 61 73  65 73 20 72  m 4 test cases r
< 0x000a0: 61 6e 2e 20  28 34 33 38  32 33 20 6d  73 20 74 6f  an. (43823 ms to
< 0x000b0: 74 61 6c 29  0d 0a 5b 20  20 50 41 53  53 45 44 20  tal)..[  PASSED 
< 0x000c0: 20 5d 20 36  37 20 74 65  73 74 73 2e  0d 0a         ] 67 tests...
```

I tried the below code, but its not matching:

```
open (FILE, '<', 'board_dumplog.log')
    or die "Could not open board_dumplog.log: $!";

while (<FILE>) {
    #print $_ if (/^[==========]/ .. /^tests.../);
    if (/^[==========]/ .. /^tests.../) {
        print "Line Found:".$_."\n";
    }
}

close (FILE)
    or die "Could not close board_dumplog.log: $!";
```

I tried one more shot with the below but no luck.

```
open (FILE, '<', '123.log') or die "Could not 123.log: $!";
my $i=0;
while (<FILE>) {

   #print $_ if (/^[==========]/ .. /^tests./);
   if (/^[0-9] tests from [0-9] test cases ran/ .. /^[0-9] tests\./){
        print "$i.Match Found:".$_."\n";
        $i++;
   }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Showing your data with a hex code editor is just needlessly complicated.  Since you're doing line by line processing, I advise that you show your data as a simple text file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly escape special chars or you should use /Q /E modifiers in regexp to match.

```
 if (/^\[[\=]+\]\s*(\d+)\s*tests/i) {
   print "found $1 tests in line: $_\n";
```

Comment: I'm getting error: bash-3.2$ perl 123.pl
Backslash found where operator expected at 123.pl line 72, near "/^\[[\=]+\]/\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
syntax error at 123.pl line 72, near "/^\[[\=]+\]/\"
Substitution replacement not terminated at 123.pl line 72.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match a literal string inside a regex, you need to escape the regex special characters.

You should learn what those special characters are, but if you want a shortcut, you can use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) or `\Q...\E`.

```
if (/^\Q[==========]\E/ .. /^\Qtests...\E/) {
```

The brackets `[]` will no longer be treated like a character class, and the periods `.` will no longer be any characters.

Comment: Lines found include [---------] instead of only [=========].